# Como fazer uma lista com os "wifis" disponiveis

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de saber como pegar todos os wifis disponíveis e colocá-los em uma lista, procurei na internet, porem não entendi direito, gostaria de um código bem resumido, obrigado.

```
public class WiFiDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{      
WifiManager wifi;       
ListView lv;
TextView textStatus;
Button buttonScan;
int size = 0;
List<ScanResult> results;

String ITEM_KEY = "key";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;

/* Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
    buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
    buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }   
    this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(WiFiDemo.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
    lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
        {
           results = wifi.getScanResults();
           size = results.size();
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                    
}

public void onClick(View view) 
{
    arraylist.clear();          
    wifi.startScan();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try 
    {
        size = size - 1;
        while (size >= 0) 
        {   
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
            item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + results.get(size).capabilities);

            arraylist.add(item);
            size--;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }         
}    
}
```

Comment: Posta o código que achou ai, mais fácil explicar o que você não entendeu do que criar um exemplo do zero.

Comment: @re22 editado, não entendi muito o bem o `WifiManager` e o `registerReceiver`

Comment: Você disse na sua pergunta que quer saber (pegar os wifis disponíveis), postou o seu código e só faltou dizer qual ou quais problemas especificamente você está encontrando.

Comment: Como não tem explicação do código, eu não entendi quase nada(para que serve cada coisa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) registra um `BroadcastReceiver` para um determinado `IntentFilter`. Isso significa que quando o evento(no seu caso) `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` acontece, o `BroadcastReceiver` que você declarou em:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
    {
       results = wifi.getScanResults();
       size = results.size();
    }
}, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

Vai recebê-lo e tratá-lo.

Resumindo, toda vez que o broadcast `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` acontecer, a sua implementação de `BroadcastReceiver` com a sua reimplementação do método `onReceive` será o responsável por tratar o broadcast. É dentro da `onReceive` que você pega o número de wifis disponíveis, como você já está fazendo com:

```
results = wifi.getScanResults();
size = results.size();
```

Comment: Poderia me mostrar uma forma de apenas salvar os "wifis" ativos em uma lista, sem executar nenhuma ação ??

Comment: Você já tem isso em `List<ScanResult> results`